# Switching between src and include files in vim

Tags: vim

I'm writing a library which is organized into two parallel and fairly deep src/ and include/ directories which contain my .cpp and .h files respectively. My favorite editor is vim, but I have yet to find a good way to quickly switch between source and header files quickly. For example, I may find myself editing

> ~/workspace/myproject/include/myproject/core/utils/coolutil.h

and decide I now need to make a small change to

> ~/workspace/myproject/src/myproject/core/utils/coolutil.cpp.

Is there a convenient and ergonomic way to handle such switches quickly in (g)vim? My current approach is to keep two NERDTrees open, one for src/ and one for include/, though I feel like there must be a less cumbersome approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170902/in-vim-how-to-switch-quickly-between-h-and-cpp-files-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function may do what you want. Put it in your ~/.vimrc or in a plugin. It assumes that all your .cpp and .h files are in parallel directories as in your example.

```
function! OpenOther()
    if expand("%:e") == "cpp"
        exe "split" fnameescape(expand("%:p:r:s?src?include?").".h")
    elseif expand("%:e") == "h"
        exe "split" fnameescape(expand("%:p:r:s?include?src?").".cpp")
    endif
endfunction

nmap ,o :call OpenOther()<CR>
```

When you have either the .cpp or the .h file open, typing `,o` will open the other in a split window.

Answer (score 3):

The alternate [plugin a.vim](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=31) solves this. It's a must have when programming in C or in C++.

Comment: a.vim seems to only want to switch between source and header files in the same directory. How can I configure it to use my parallel source/include directory trees?

Comment: You have to set `g:alternateSearchPath` with the correct regexes. e.g. `let g:alternateSearchPath = 'reg:#\<src\>$#include#,reg:#\<include\>$#src#'` to switch between `path/to/source/include` and `path/to/source/src`